# Move a default text as you type in a textbox along with text typed

Tags: javascript, jquery

default text is "Move"

```
-------------------------------------
|Move                                |
|                                    |
|                                    |
-------------------------------------

-------------------------------------
|W Move                              |
|                                    |
|                                    |
-------------------------------------

-------------------------------------
|Wo Move                             |
|                                    |
|                                    |
-------------------------------------

-------------------------------------
|Wow Move                            |
|                                    |
|                                    |
-------------------------------------
```

As I start typing letters "w" "o" "w" default text "Move" move to right as a new letter append to the text box.

I searched for sometime but din't get any right pointer to achieve this. Hope to get someone would be able to point me towards the right direction.

Here is a jsfiddle page I have so far, http://jsfiddle.net/jsnewbie/xmtFM/2/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm just a touch confused what you want to do. Do you want the move to append to each letter? Do you want it to append to the end of each word typed?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you'd need JavaScript to accomplish this? If some one were to just click in the box before the word Move, the default functionality for a textbox would accomplish exactly what you desire.

Comment: Thanks, true that but depends on the user where he clicks before the default text "move" or after the text. In my case if default text stays at the end of the user's sentence would make sense. In my current effort I'm trying to find out if moving the default text as new letters are typed is elegant and better UX if not i will stick to default but in the process I will learn javascript

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

Backspace and a bit responsive as @KevinB suggested

```
var store = $('textarea').val();
console.log(store);
var newVal = [];
$("textarea").focus(function () {
    console.log(store);
}).keydown(function (e) {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (e.keyCode !== 8) {
            var curr = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
            newVal.push(curr);
            console.log(newVal + store);
        } else { // Backspace
            e.preventDefault();
            if (newVal.length > 0) newVal.pop();
        }
        $(self).val(newVal.join('') + " " + store);
    }, 20);
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/xmtFM/9/)**

Comment: looking at that fiddle you cant seem to delete anything once you type it in.

Comment: a little more responsive: http://jsfiddle.net/xmtFM/6/ need to make it preserve case though, and stop losing "Move" on focus

Comment: @zazvorniki.. added support for backspace.. Also this is a very rudimentary way of handling it. There may be better approaches than this

Comment: Thanks Sushanth for taking a stab at this. This is much closer what was my intention to achieve. There are issues like cursor is at the end, delete and arrows doesn't do justice. However, this is a good pointer, I will go through to understand and if I can improve upon to accomplish in a elegant manner.

Comment: @radiant.. Glad to have helped !!

Comment: thanks to zazvorniki and Kevin B, feel awesome to get these responses.